# How to work getFieldValue for assets

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, assets, user-profile, assets-field

I have been implementing my own PHP plugin code.

In that, I need to get an asset field in user info. If I can get if the asset is set on the field or not, it is enough.

I can get the values of text and radio button fields with `$user->getFieldValue` function.
However, it does not work for asset fields.
How should I do for asset?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by myself.

```
$asset = $user->getFieldValue(FIELDHANDLE)->one();
$user->setFieldValues([ 'FIELDHANDLE' => $asset->filename ]);
```